# Using exposed filters as part of the rendered page's title

Tags: views

I'm using exposed filters in a Drupal 7 site. I'd like to make the **selected items** from those filters part of the titles. Is there a way I can get the text value of those selected filters and use that text as part of the title?

Settings are as allowed:

[image]

I'm also using [Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) in this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A also have this question. But now I'm trying this module: https://drupal.org/project/exposed_filter_data?
And this module is not working for me.

I found this:

```
/**
 * THEME_PREPROCESS_VIEWS_VIEW
 * @param type $vars
 * 
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'viewName') {
    // get var from GET
    $obj_type = $_GET['obj_type'];
    if (isset($obj_type)) {
      // obj_type is the taxonomy term, get taxonomy term name
      $tax_name=taxonomy_term_load($obj_type)->name;
      // if taxonomy term have parents
      $tax_parent = taxonomy_get_parents_all($obj_type);
      if (isset($tax_parent[1])) {
        // add parent name to taxonomy term name
        $tax_name =  $tax_parent[1]->name . ', ' . $tax_name;
      }
      //update title
      $vars['view']->build_info['title'] = $tax_name;
    }
}
```

And this is working!

Comment: You can also use $vars['view']->exposed_input which gives the same data as $_GET but only contains exposed input related items, which is better if you want to loop over multiple filters and/or avoid hardcoding vocabulary machine names (it's worth mentioning that `obj_type` in this example code is an example vocabulary machine name).

Answer (score 0):

(Yes, I know this is an old question, but better late than never?)

If you're wanting to use the exposed filter settings as part of the `<title>` tag, you can do something similar to:

```
function hook_process_html(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['head_title']) && $uri = request_uri()) {
    $variables['head_title'] .= " ($uri)";
  }
}
```

If you were wanting to change the view title as it appears on the page, it's best done in `preprocess_views_view()` as mentioned by VVS.

Comment: See also [How to programmatically change a Views page's html <title> separately to its on-page <h1>title</h1>?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239935/how-to-programmatically-change-a-views-pages-html-title-separately-to-its-on/) if you need to do something requiring more views data than just the uri